# Authentication app engine using google apps domain

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I created a new application, set the authentication to users of a specific google apps domain. 
I've created accounts and added this app into myexampledomain.mygbiz.com

I'm using java with Eclipse.
When i upload this app to GAE, no login request. Everyone can access...

How can I request users login before visit this app?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set login required into your app.yaml file:

```
handlers:
- url: .*
  login: required
```

For more info: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status